# php composer - unitTest

Tags: php, composer

Только знакомлюсь с композером и юнит тестами. Установил юнит тесты через композер. Так выглядит json-файл:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/var-dumper": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.4"
    }
}
```

При попытке создать класс унаследованный от PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase я получил fatal error - что такой класс не найден..

На офоц. сайте PHPUnit, увидел такую запись \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase - которая помогла:

```
class AppTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {...}
```

Насколько я понял, это связано со стандартами psr-0 и psr-4 ? Как это настраивается для композера? В каких случаях можно один вид записи использовать, в каких - второй (через нижнее подчеркивание вместе обратного слэша)? В чем преимущества одного и второго?

Также хотел понять, можно ли менять расположение папки vendor композера, как это делать, и чем чревато?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличие \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase от \PHPUnit\_Framework\_TestCase, и директории vendor для композера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907907/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-phpunit-framework-testcase-%d0%be%d1%82-phpunit-framework-testcase-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Пожалуйста, [ведите себя вежливо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: @u_mulder, здесь есть ответ, потому **тот** вопрос надо закрыть как дубликат, а не **этот**.

Comment: Если сравните даты то вопрос я пометил дубликатом __до того__ как тут появился ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Как вы верно ответили существует два стандарта автозагрузки в php [psr-0](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) и [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). Psr-4 это обновлённый улучшенный psr-0. Одно из важных различий является загрузка через _ например:

- Файл находится в */src/classes/Test.php* должен называться **Src_Classes_Test**

Такая автозагрузка встречается для устаревшего фреймворка zend framework 1.
Настраевается в composer:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Zend_": "library/"
        }
},
```

Для psr-4 пример:
 - Файл находится в */src/classes/Test.php* должен вызваться **Src/Classes/Test**

Настраивается:

```
"autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
      }
},
```

Не забывайте что для стандарта [psr-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) для длинных названий класса следует использовать:

```
use \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase as TestCase;

class AppTest extends TestCase {}
```

Vendor можно поменять, но обычно меняют в случае необходимости:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir

```
"config": {
        "vendor-dir": "libs"
    }
```